# HackerEarth - Codemonk - Circular Equation Problem

Tags: python, equation, circular-dependency

Hi folks I am solving a problem `Circular Equation` in `Python 3.8.10` language and this problem is on `HackerEarth Platform` under `Codemonk/Number` Theory Part I* section and below I have attached exact problem and explanation that I get from the `HackerEarth Platform`:

Given S, find the count of possible values of N which satisfy below condition:

Given `N, F(N,i)` represent a number which is generated by shifting the digits of N cyclically towards left by i units.

N must satisfy given condition:
`S = Summation { F(N,i) } for all i from 0 to |N| - 1 , where |N| represent number of digits in N`.

N can have leading zeroes. As the number of N can be very large output it modulo `1000000000 + 7`.

**Input:**

- First line contain an integer Q, denoting number of queries.
- Next Q lines contain an integer S.

**Output:**

- Print a single integer in separate line corresponding to each Query.

**Constraint:**

- 1 <= Q <= 1e5
- 1 <= S <= 1e18

**Sample Input:**

```
1
55
```

**Sample Output:**

```
6
```

**Explanation**
`N = 05, 50, 14, 41, 23, 32 satisfy given conditions.`

Time Limit: 1.0 sec(s) for each input file
Memory Limit: 256 MB
Source Limit: 1024 KB

My solution is:

```
MOD = 1000000007
def count_possible_values(S):
    def sum_of_cyclic_shifts(N):
        n_str = str(N)
        total = 0
        for i in range(len(n_str)):
            total += int(n_str[i:] + n_str[:i])
        return total % MOD

    count = 0

    for N in range(S + 1):
        if sum_of_cyclic_shifts(N) == S:
            count += 1
    return count

Q = int(input())
for _ in range(Q):
    S = int(input())
    result = count_possible_values(S)
    print(result)

# input
# 1
# 55
# ouput
# 241109225
# expected output will be
# 6
```

but when I run my code the output is: 241109225
and my expected output is: 6
because on final result I am calculating total numbers of combination

Comment: Your code outputs 5, not 241109225 for me. The problem here is that you're not taking into account the cases with leading zeros. In the example you give, you're missing `n_str="05"`, which gives `05 + 50 = 55`

Comment: Yes, I don't know why this is happening but I still didn't get expected correct output that is 6